# androidstudio how to generate /build/intermediates/proguard-files/proguard-android.txt-2.3.1

Tags: android

Execution failed for task ':chatcore:proguardJar'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jake/workspace/mango/project/MangoSdk/build/intermediates/proguard-files/proguard-android.txt-2.3.1 (No such file or directory)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [related task in the android plugin](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/7672f299c2c18b4a7801316154558264ca7129da/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/tasks/ExtractProguardFiles.java).

You should make your task depend on the *extractProguardFiles* task, and then the default proguard configs will be copied to your build directory from the android sdk.

In the chatcore project's build file, add this line:

```
proguardJar.dependsOn tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ExtractProguardFiles)
```

Please note that this particular task itself is not public API, so it may break in the future!